# Write a program that can draw 2-D shapes using ASCII or any other method

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art

Rules (not too restrictive; flexible):

1.Must be able to draw shapes on command (e.g., I type in "square" and a square is drawn).

Minimum completed shapes that can be drawn on command: Square, Circle, Triangle, Pentagon.

2.Must also be able to also draw shapes vertex-by-vertex, specified by a command function that gives the user an input to determine line segment lengths between points in succession.

The program has to give the option to make polygons as well, but incomplete 2-D shapes, circles, unclosed planes, and non-polygons shall be allowed.

Winner: Most votes.

Comment: I only see two things wrong: What happens if the line segments do not make a polygon. E.g. 10, 50, 10. Other thing: Do you really want only ascii-art? If yes, why? Isn't graphical output ok?

Comment: @Victor It actually doesn't have to be only polygons, but I added an extra rule that the program must give the option to the user on whether or not the shapes must be polygons(e.g., a circle isn't a polygon). Also, it doesn't have to be only ASCII-art, so experimentation is welcome.

Comment: Rule# 1 is fairly trivial. Rule #2 is underspecified.  For polygons with more than three edges, the edge lengths do not constrain the shape of the resulting figure.

Comment: Next time, don't forget to run your question through the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/954/9498)

Answer (score 2):

## Logo

Just install it!

Then things like triangles, squares, pentagons and circles are defined as:

```
to triangle :length
    polygon :length 3
end

to square :length
    polygon :length 4
end

to pentagon :length
    polygon :length 5
end

to circle :length
    polygon :length 360
end

to polygon :length :sides
    repeat :sides [forward :length right 360/:sides]
end
```

Easy peasy lemon squeezy...

Comment: You should do circle, triangle, and pentagon, too.

Comment: Okay, no problem. Done.